# MongoDB Ruby driver and mongoS

Tags: ruby, mongodb, bson

I am trying to use the MongoDB Ruby driver to pull information from a cluster via mongoS.  Here is what I've done.

```
@mongo_client = Mongo::Connection.new('mongoshost', 27320)
@db = @mongo_client.db("thedatabase")
@auth = @db.authenticate("username", "password")
if(@mongo_client)
  print "Successfully connected to mongos\n"
else
  print "Connection failed"
end
if(@auth == true)
  print "Auth successful\n"
else
print "Auth failed"
  end
collection = @db.collection("thecollection")
puts collection.find.to_a
```

When I run this, everything works up until the point that it tries to print the documents in the collection.  Here's what my output looks like:

```
C:\Code\whatever>ruby getdata.rb
Successfully connected to mongos
Auth successful
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bson-1.9.2/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:24:in `deseria
lize': time must be positive (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bson-1.9.2/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:2
4:in `deserialize'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/networkin
g.rb:223:in `read_documents'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/networkin
g.rb:169:in `receive'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/networkin
g.rb:133:in `receive_message'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:497:in `block in send_initial_query'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/logg
ing.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/logg
ing.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/logg
ing.rb:54:in `instrument'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:493:in `send_initial_query'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:478:in `refresh'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:124:in `next'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:290:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:314:in `to_a'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb
:314:in `to_a'
        from getdata.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

The "time must be positive" error had a few search results, but nothing that helped me figure out what the issue is.  One of the fields in these documents does hold a negative number for a date, but I'm not sure why that's an issue since it's reading it and not writing (For example, one of the fields looks like so: {"md" : Date(-62135596800000)})

Is this an issue with the driver, is my code bad, or do I need to figure this out in another manner?  I'm pretty new to ruby so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is bad as you have already noted. The problem is that the driver is trying to expand the date value ( which is really just a number internally to mongo within a BSON timestamp field ) into a real DateTime object.

When it tries to do this on read, the number is invalid an the inflation fails. If you fix the date value the problem will be corrected.

**Note**: If you do this in the shell use the [ISOate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) helper to put a correct value in. If you use code then use a DateTime object. Don't use strings as you will mess your data up further.

Comment: @idofxeno Glad it helped your understanding. Can I add that it is good practice here to **accept** your accepted answers as it helps keep things relevant on the site to answered/un-answered and which responses are valid. Thanks for your participation.